# character encoding - importing HTML into Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, character-encoding, utf-8

I exported my Google Chrome (browser) bookmarks as an HTML file and then imported that file into Microsoft Excel.

After importing, the text looks bad in Excel.

E.g., the word "don't" in the HTML file turns into string in the image below after import into Excel.

[image]

I realize this is a "character encoding" issue. I've never fully understood character encoding, and this might be my opportunity to understand it. What can I do, in terms of changing the "character encoding" in Excel, to read this HTML file properly?

Comment: Maybe some info here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAB0sDpL-ls

Comment: @Bandersnatch Thanks, but it didn't help.